# AttributeError: 'Michael' object has no attribute '_class_'

Tags: python, class

I just started learning Python and I got a problem here. I copied the following code from my textbook, so I should work.

```
class Michael:
    def _init_(self,max):
        self.count = 0
        self.max = 5

    def teach(self):
        if self._class_.count < self._class_max:
            print("play harder!")
        else:
            print("Well done!")
        self._class_count += 1

oni1 = Michael()
for i in range(4):
    print("smash!")
    oni1.teach()
oni2 = Michael()
for i in range(2):
    print("backstroke")
oni2.teach()
```

But my editor gave me the message below. 
(AttributeError: 'Michael' object has no attribute '*class*')
Also, it also said that the line 16 is also wrong, although it didn't tell me how I made a mistake.  I would appreciate if you provide me with solutions for the problems above.

Comment: Use double underscores `__class__`, `__init__` etc.

Comment: @HåkenLid The class doesn't have a `count` attribute though, so that can't be right. The code is incomplete. The `_class_max` and `_class_count` attributes aren't being created anywhere either.

Comment: Which line is __line 16__?

Comment: There's more than one problem here. The `self.__class__` attribute does exits, since it's inherited from `object`. But `self._class_count` and `self._class_max` are not defined anywhere.

Comment: Also, I would beware of a textbook that creates a class named *Michael*. What are you gonna do with that, create a bunch of Michaels? Is this a cloning experiment?

Comment: Line 16 is oni1.teach().  So sorry that I forgot to mention that.